# Prove that there is a vertex that is connected to $d$ leaves.

Tags: graph-theory

We know that (*):

> If $T$ a tree Graph contains a vertex $v$ with $rank(v)=d$ then the tree includes at least $d$ leaves.

Given a tree graph $T(V,E)$ that has at least $3$ vertices.

For every $v\in T$ that is not a leaf we get that $rank(v)>d$.

**We need to prove that :** There is a vertex $v$ that belongs to $T$ that is connected at least to $d$ leaves.

I'm not sure if we need the (*)  described up there but I'm not able to prove this or even to grasp the idea of the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Take any vertex middle vertex $v$.
- If $v$ is adjacent to $d$ leaves, finish.
- Otherwise paint $v$ black and consider next any of its neighbors which aren't leaves and aren't painted (there will be at most one painted).
- The tree is finite, so the black path cannot go on forever.

I hope it helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: I got that we get a black path but did not understand how this can help us in proving that there is a vertex that is adjacent to $d$ leaves :\ can you explain a little bit more ?

Comment: @WasFr What kind of vertex ends the black path?

Comment: oh it is a vertex that is connected to $d$ leaves.
I got it ! elegant solution (Y)